# Determine how many times a specific value occurs around each element of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing a program that is a Game of Thrones Game similar to minesweeper. The user is asked for the size of the kingdom and depending on the size has a certain amount of knights. I create a matrix (size by size) of zeros to pre-allocate and assign the same amount of kings as there are knights to random places in the matrix. I now have made a new function that i call in the main script that i want to iterate through the matrix and assign new values to each element based on how many kings are in the neighboring spots for example:

```
_ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

1 * 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

2 1 2 2 * 2 2 1 1

3 1 2 * 3 * 2 * 1

4 * 3 1 2 1 2 1 1

5 * 2 0 0 0 0 0 0

6 1 0 0 1 1 2 1 1

7 1 1 1 1 * 2 * 1

8 1 * 1 1 1 2 1 1
```

The problem is I really do not know how to actually count the neighboring kings and change the values in my matrix. I have started with some for loops for the sides but i am not sure how to proceed. The main scrips and the function are bellow Thank you!

Main Script:

```
clear all;close all;clc;
%display menu of options to play gam or exit 
choice = menu('Choose an option', 'Exit Program', 'Start New Game');
%choise 1 is to exit the program 
while choice ~= 1
   switch choice
       case 0
           disp('Error - please choose one of the options.')
           choice = menu('Choose an option', 'Exit Program', 'Start New Game');
%choice two is to start a new game 
       case 2
           disp('Welcome to the GAME of THRONES!');
           name = input('State your name, Your Grace: ','s');
           size = input(['How vast is your Kindom ', name , ' your Grace?: ']);
           Kings = floor((size^2)/6);
           A = [name, ' Your Grace, you have ' num2str(Kings), ' Knights left to defeat ' num2str(Kings), ' Kings'];
           disp(A);
         game_choices =  menu('Choose an option','Show the Kingdoms','Enter a new Coordinat');
         switch game_choices 
             case 1 %Show the board 
                            mymat = zeros(size);%matrix of users size 
                                Kr=randsample(size^2,Kings);%vector of random positions for the kings 
                            for i= 1:Kings
                                mymat([Kr(i)])=999;%put kings into mat of zeros in there random assignments
                            end
                            makeBoard(size);
                            %cell array game board 

             case 2  %enter a new coordinate 

         end
   end     
 choice = menu('Choose an option', 'Exit Program', 'Start New Game');          
end
```

Function i do not know how to write:

```
function [ mymatG ] = countTheKings( mymat )
%this function counts the kings and puts the numbers where they should be
%should have 2 for loops 
for i = 1:size
    for j = 1:size
        %top
        mymat(1,j)=
        %bottom
        mymat(size,j)=
        %left side
        mymat(i,1)=
        %right side
        mymat(i,size)=



end
```

Answer (score 2):

A classic way to count the number of neighbors is to use [convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html). 2D Convolution, in the discrete world, shifts a matrix ("kernel") over a bigger matrix and for each shift, the overlap is computed. The overlap is defined as the sum of the element-wise multiplication of the kernel and the data underneath of it. The resulting value is then used to replace the value that the kernel is centered on.

We can design the kernel to "detect" neighbors. We want it to have ones in spots that you consider to be neighbors and zeros in spots that you *don't* consider to be neighbors. This would probably look like this if you don't want your kings to consider themselves a neighbor.

```
1  1  1
1  0  1
1  1  1
```

This matrix will be centered at every point on your board and element-wise multiplication with the board will be performed and all elements will be summed up.

For example, if this was centered at the following data

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

It would be processed as:

```
(1 * 1) + (2 * 1) + (3 * 1) + (4 * 1) + (5 * 0) + (6 * 1) + (7 * 1) + (8 * 1) + (9 * 1)
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 0 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9
40
```

So we can also use convolution of this "kernel" to *count* the number of 1's in a binary matrix.

So for this data

```
1  0  1
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

When we apply our kernel to this we get

```
(1 * 1) + (0 * 1) + (1 * 1) + (0 * 1) + (0 * 0) + (0 * 1) + (1 * 1) + (0 * 1) + (0 * 1)
1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0
3
```

If you imagine that the binary data we applied this kernel to was 1 where there is a king and 0 where there isn't, this is the number of kings that surround a given element.

So what we can do is take the kernel from the beginning of our question, and create a binary matrix that is 1's where there is a king and 0's otherwise. The result will be the size of your board and the values will be the number of neighboring kings.

```
kernel = [1 1 1;
          1 0 1;
          1 1 1];

mymat = [9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 9 0 0 0 0
         0 0 9 0 9 0 9 0
         9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 9 0 9 0
         0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0];

isKing = mymat == 9;

nKingNeighbors = conv2(double(isKing), kernel, 'same');

%//     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
%//     1     2     2     2     2     2     1     1
%//     1     2     1     3     1     2     0     1
%//     1     3     1     2     1     2     1     1
%//     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
%//     1     1     0     1     1     2     1     1
%//     1     1     1     1     0     2     0     1
%//     1     0     1     1     1     2     1     1
```

If you didn't want to consider diagonal entries to be neighbors you could simply change your kernel to be.

```
0  1  0
1  0  1
0  1  0
```

So if we take this back to your example, we could write your `countTheKings` function as

```
function mymatG = countTheKings(mymat)
    kernel = [1 1 1
              1 0 1
              1 1 1];
    mymatG = conv2(double(mymat == 999), kernel, 'same');
end
```

Here is an animation showing what the 2D convolution is actually doing. The kernel is shown in red and you can see the values of `nKingNeighbors` being filled in as the kernel is shifted over the image.

[image]

Comment: @user6153565 Test it out and be sure to mark it as the solution if it solves your problem.